# Error obteniendo datos en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código en un programa de Python 3.7.0 que en teoría no debería dar error:

```
    import pyodbc
import csv

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=EDISOFT')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for row in cursor.execute ("select top 100 isbn,ean, titulo, pvp from art"):
    print (row.isbn, row.ean, row.titulo, row.pvp )
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Sin embargo me arroja:

AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'isbn'

Si en lugar del nombre de la columna pongo el ordinal del campo row[0] no me da error.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Falta ver la tabla, porque el error que sale es que la tabla que consultas no tiene esa columna.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías usar cursor.fetchall() según la [documentación de pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)

El código quedaría de este modo

```
import pyodbc
import csv

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=EDISOFT')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select top 100 isbn,ean, titulo, pvp from art")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row.isbn, row.ean, row.titulo, row.pvp )
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

**EDITO:**

Parece que en rows no está devolviendo objetos row, tal y como sujiere la documentación.

Te propongo la siguiente solución, crear una función que trasforme el resultado del cursor en una lista de diccionarios para facilitar la referencia a nombre de campos. El código prodría quedar así:

```
import pyodbc

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
            dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
           ]

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=EDISOFT')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select top 100 isbn,ean, titulo, pvp from art")
rows = cursor.dictfetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row.get('isbn'), row.get('ean'), row.get('titulo'), row.get('pvp'))
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Otra solucion sin tener que utilizar la función para pasar el resultado a una lista de diccionarios puede ser cambiar la sentencia sql por la siguiente

```
cursor.execute('select top 100 "isbn" as isbn, "ean" as ean, "titulo" as titulo, "pvp" as pvp from art')
```

Parece que en algunas conexiones requiere un formato como este.

Comment: Hola, sí, en efecto así es como lo hice a principio pero da el mismo error.

Comment: Comenta por favor, que aparece si a este código le haces un print(rows) debajo del fetchall() y dejando comentado el bucle for

Comment: Si hago eso me trae los datos sin ningún error.

Comment: Entonces lo tienes resuelto? Si no es asi, pega aqui el resultado de rows para poder ver que devuelve, por favor.

Comment: No, disculpa, no me he explicado bien. Me devuelve bien el resultado si no le pido ningún campo por nombre de campo. El problema viene cuando quiero llamar a un campo con un print(row.nombrecampo) . Tengo algunas tablas que son muy grandes, con muchos campos y si no es un lío acordarse del índice de dicho campo.

Comment: Entiendo el problema, pero que devuelve el print de rows? Una lista de tuplas? Una lista de listas? Si pones un pequeño ejemplo de lo que te esta devolviendo lo veré más claro

Comment: Este es el resultado: (Lo pego como respuesta)

Comment: Creo que tengo una solución para este caso, he editado el respuesta, pruebalo y me dices.

Comment: Si utilizo la función me da el mismo error, si utilizo la query modificaca el driver odbc da error. De cualquier forma creo que es un error de pyodbc, si no no me lo explico. He leído la documentación varias veces y no debería tener problemas utilizando row.nombre_comlumna. Gracias, Cecilio, al final utilizaré row[indice] .

Comment: Revisa lo de la función, porque yo utilizo esa función habitualmente para ciertas cosas con pyobdc y me funciona sin problemas. De todos modos, para que quede más limpia la pregunta, lo adecuado sería borrar la respuesta que la que muestras el resultado de rows si te es posible.

Comment: Hecho, le daré una vuelta a tu función. Muchas gracias de nuevo.